# C (UNIX), Combining files (number of bytes)

Tags: c, unix, command-line, command

So I am trying to combine any number of given files in the order provided and print the output to std output. The filenames and specifications are given through UNIX command line. I have input validation working completely, I am just having trouble figuring out how to put my thoughts into C syntax (i have never coded in C before).

&g will combine entire file
&qN (N being an integer) will combine only the first N bytes
&uN (N being an integer) will combine only the last N bytes

The way I am thinking would be best is open the file with fopen, figure out how big it is and make a buffer that big, then read into  that buffer (with fread) and write the buffer (with fwrite). I feel like the solution is rather simple, and should not be more than a few lines.

My attempt for the first spec &g is below. I can only get so far because this is a very new language to me.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file, "r");

// if file fails to open - file is not found
if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("file %s does not exist", file);
}
else
{
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(file_sz));
 }
```

Comment: why not just use getline and read and print each line one at a time?

Comment: Please ask a specific question. We won't do the whole thing for you. So what specifically do you need help with? You have allocated the buffer, now read the file. It may not be the best solution to start with but at least implement as much as you can. Then ask a specific question once you get stuck on particular issue.

Comment: And `malloc(sizeof(file_sz));`  should be `malloc(file_sz);`

Comment: More specifically, my issue is I do not even know if I am going the right direction with this. How can I combine files? Once I know that the only thing left to figure out is how can I specify which bytes to combine. That makes me lost, as I have no clue where to start (I do not know this language very well).

Comment: It's unclear that you really need to "combine" files. The description says "print the output to std output". Which does not require "combining". Just read as much of each file as needed and print it out as you go. If you really do need to "combine files" then please clarify what that means - e.g. does it mean produce an output file with the combined content?

Comment: Sorry if i'm being not specific (english is not my native language). I just want to combine any number of files (whole thing or in part). I want to write combined result to standard output and redirect that to a new file.

Comment: For example: myprogram &g random.txt &q15 otherfile.txt       will combine the entire random.txt file and only the first 15 bytes of otherfile.txt into a new file

Comment: Like I said, why do you need to combine before printing? Just read first file and output. Then read next file and output, etc. No need for collecting the entire combined content first.

Comment: Because the way my input validation is setup is it reads the spec then at the end of my nested if statements (validating the correct format) it executes the file operation (combining). Since there are 3 options I am trying to do it the way I stated in my original post because there are 3 nested if statement structures

Comment: So you are saying you have implemented something which is not ideal and you don't want to change it even though there is a better way? Doesn't make sense right?

Comment: I want to do it the way I said because i am not going to spend another 6+ hours coding a different way to do it. I am new to C and programming in general so I cannot do this in 30 minutes like you probably can. You're not helping here, mate.

Comment: @Vno If you want to learn programming then you need to spend hours to implement things correctly. If you ask a question here but you don't want to hear answers, then don't ask. Remark: don't allocate memory to put a full file inside, this is not the way you can manage **all** possible files.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a rudimentary example that could be used to get something good up and running.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buffer[1001]; // NYI - no magic numbers. Static size....

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  for(int x=1; x<argc; x++) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[x], "r+");
    if (fp) {
      while(fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)) { // NYI - no magic numbers 
        printf("%s", buffer);
      }
    } else {
      printf("could NOT open file %s\n", argv[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `fgets/fprintf`  is unnecessary as raw copy suffice since OP wants to copy the whole file as-is. `fread/fwrite` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to change a few things for this to work with my code but i'm glad it is working. How can I make it print the last few N bytes of a file?